# Django Form Not Saving, Terminal Shows Data & Save Method Added

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

All I'm trying to do is save the simple form. Everything looks fine but after I click save and the form is re-rendered there is no new trade in the Database. No error message is thrown either.

At first, I thought there was an issue with the user but it looks fine as well. Been reading a lot of documentation on this topic but haven't found where the issue is yet.

Thanks for any help and please let me know if there is anything extra I can add.

create.html

```
        <form id='trade_create_view' method='POST' action='.'>

            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}

            <input type='submit' value='Submit' >
        </form>
```

views.py

```
def trade_create_view(request):
    form = TradeForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        form.save()
        form = TradeForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, "tj/cp/trade/create.html", context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Trade


class TradeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Trade
        fields = [
            'user',
            'target_size',
            'target_entry',
            'target_exit',
            'ticker',
            'exchange',
            'short',
            'comments',
            'size',
            'entry_price',
            'exit_price',
            'entry_date',
            'exit_date',
            'fees',
            'permission',
        ]

        exclude = ['user',]
```

model.py

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True)

    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_edit = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    #general trade info
    ticker = models.ForeignKey(Ticker, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    short = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    exchange = models.ForeignKey(Exchange, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    #target trade outline
    target_size = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=50, decimal_places=20)
    target_entry = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=50, decimal_places=20)
    target_exit = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=50, decimal_places=20)

    #real trade
    size = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=50, decimal_places=20)
    entry_price = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=50, decimal_places=20)
    exit_price = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=50, decimal_places=20)
    entry_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default=datetime.now)
    exit_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default=datetime.now)
    fees = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=50, decimal_places=20)

    PER_OPTIONS = [
        ('0', 'Public'),
        ('1', 'Private'),
        ('2', 'Mentor Only'),
    ]
    permission = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PER_OPTIONS, default=0)
```

Comment: HINT: in your `trade_create_view` check for the request type if it is 'GET' or 'POST'

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to check if your request is a post or a get method:

```
def trade_create_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TradeForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            form.save()
            form = TradeForm()

   context = {
      'form': form,
   }

   return render(request, "tj/cp/trade/create.html", context)
```

OR

You just can add a post def to your view as follows:

```
def post(self, request):
    form = TradeForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        form.save()
        form = TradeForm()
...
```

Comment: adding the "if request.method == "POST":" didn't help. Will try it as a class-based view.

Comment: I posted the final answer. Thanks for the help. I tried it the way you had above and it also not update the database at first. Your way is 100% right as well as I saw it numerous times in the documentation. The way I did it was apparently a more shortcut way to do it from what I read in the docs. The real issue seems to have been some sort of database delay..

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't make sens: `TradeForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)`

When you use `instance` for your form, you give an instance of the object concerned. But your object is `Trade` not `User`. You can choose different ways to solve the problem, I give one:

```
def trade_create_view(request, id):
    form = TradeForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        trade, created = Trade.objects.get_or_create(id=id)    # you get or create your instanced Trade
        form = TradeForm(request.POST, instance=trade)   # you give to your form the instance of your Trade
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            form.save()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, "tj/cp/trade/create.html", context)
```

I arbitrarily took the `id` to query an object `Trade`. As I understand your code you can use this function to create and edite any `Trade` object with your `TradeForm`.

[get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) is document on the Django Website. If you don't when to use it, you can use `Trade.objects.get(id=id)` you you need to check if the object exist before.

But if you **just when to create** an object `Trade` just remove `instance=XXX`, and use `TradeForm(request.POST)`. Instance is used to get an object in your database and overwrite with the new data  posted and processed by your form.

Answer (score 0):

So I switched everything over to Class-Based Views and for some reason now it works perfectly and instantly.

What came even more as a shock is that when I checked my database again after the first Class-Based View test there were about 15 test trades that now appeared (and trust me I checked/refreshed the database after every function view test). So.. I guess it worked all along which is nice because I really read the documentation 10x to figure out what was wrong and was getting really frustrated. What's not so nice is that the database took hours to update or maybe they were frozen somewhere else. That I can't explain yet.

the new views.py

```
class TradeCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = "tj/cp/trade/create.html"
    form_class = TradeForm
    queryset = Trade.objects.all()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

I know this maybe not the perfect resolve you guys were hoping for but at least there is some closure.